# running ajax to del a record when clicking anchor

Tags: django, jquery

I'm new in jquery and ajax,but I've just learned how to post a form using jquery ajax and save it,now I have a list of records in a table in my template ,some thing like this:

```
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" id="rec1">del</a>
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" id="rec2">del</a>
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" id="rec2">del</a>
...
```

now I wanna remove a record when clicking on its anchor tag.

**Edit:**
these records have already have been inserted into database using ajax and immediately have been shown in this format in a table,now I'm going to remove each record by clicking on its `anchor` by ajax.

like this:

```
field1  field2  field3 <a href="#" id="rec2" onClick="f({{id}})">del</a>
```

how can I do this?

Comment: just out of curiosity: are you saving those records inside a database? if so, you would need a django view to delete a record, and call it using jquery

Answer (score 3):

i'll try

*first*: you need to have a django view to delete the selected item

*second*: define a pattern in your url file that points at that view,say

```
(r'^delete/(\d{4})/$', 'delete_item'),
```

then your javascript should be something like this:

```
function deleteAjax(item_id){
$.ajax({
    url: "delete/"+ item_id +"/",
    data: <the id of the record you want to delete>,
    success: function(){
        //here you do the processing needed to remove the row from the html;
    }
});
}
```

your html then must change:

```
<a id="{{id}}" onclick="deleteAjax({{id}}); return false;"> delete item </a>
```

the click event will trigger the javascript (deleteAjax) and call the correct (django) view by sending it the id of the item to delete

just a few things to note:

- the django view must handle the correct response, since it will determine which callback will be called at the end of its execution (it's that ajax part "success: function...", you can have also a failure: function)
- in the success function you must remeber to remove the table row corresponding to the deleted item (if success in deletion) or you must notify (if failure)

last: i'm not sure now about that "data" parameter you send in the ajax function, since the id of the deleted item is binded to the url. Still, you can use that to send whatever you'll eventually need

Comment: how can I access sent data using ajax in my view?

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like onClick="$(this).closest('tr').remove()"

Assuming that its an actual table as you said being that you have html like this

```
<table><tr><td/><td/></tr></table>
```

Comment: I'm going to remove it from database using ajax!your suggestion may be my second problem after removing record from database.

Answer (score 0):

@Samuele it worked! :D

tnx,now that sounds like my success function doesn't work:

```
function f(id) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/meeting/delParticipant/"+id+"/",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {'id':id},
                    success: function(res){
                        alert ('success');
                        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    }
                });
            };
```

I'm going to remove the row in table,I used alert to test it and I'm sure that success doesn't run!